# How can buyer details be shown on paypal's order summary page?

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to submit other information to the paypal order summary page aside from just the product name and price? I have a form that submits to paypal and it contains the buyer's email address and their name which I would like it to appear on the summary page. 
Can someone please post a small snippet of what the button code would look like for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once buyer login to their paypal account during checkout, the buyer will be able to see their email and shipping address as shown in the image for PayPal Payment Standard buttons such as buynow, addto cart.

If you are using Express checkout Integration, you can use [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) API to retrieve the buyer information and display in the order summary page on your website(not in paypal checkout page).
[image]

Comment: This is true, but I need to show somewhere on the summary that the person making the purchase is the person who will be receiving the product, or not. The buyer is not always the person who will be receiving my product. This is why I need to capture on the paypal summary the additional information from my site's order form that brought them to paypal when they submitted the order. My order form asks them to provide the actual person's contact information if it is someone other than the person paying for it.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not possible to display the buyer information in paypal checkout page(www.paypal.com/......), you can only get the buyer information and display in your website not on paypal checkout page.